# How to make an observe at the moment in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I have a problem in this code:

```
    func calculaGastos() -> Float{
    let idUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName
    var total : Float = 0
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(idUser!).child("Gastos")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        if(value != nil){
            for i in value!{
                let j = i.value as? NSDictionary
                let precio = j?["precio"] as? Float
                let fecha = j?["Fecha"] as? String
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"
                let date = dateFormatter.date(from: fecha!)
                if(((date?.timeIntervalSinceNow)! * -1) < (30*24*3600)){
                    print("Total:" ,total)
                    total += precio!

                }
            }
        }
        print("Calculing in the function", total)

    }
    return total
}
```

Which is called in a override function in another view controller and the logs shows that in the print of the viewdidload is 0, but in the function print is show that is printed as 30 but return 0 all time, I believe that the problem is that it returns before enter in the observer but I'm not sure any solutions for this?

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    nomUser.text = id?.displayName!
    correoLabel.text = id?.email!
    print("Calculing in View Controller", calculo.calculaBenef(), calculo.calculaGastos())
    gastosField.text = String(calculo.calculaGastos())
    benefField.text = String(calculo.calculaBenef())
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Here is my log:
[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3iEI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within an app I'm currently working on, I ran into a similar issue. The solution was to implement a dispatch group in the function. I also changed the way your function returns `total` so that it's now being returned by a completion handler.

Try this instead:

```
 func calculaGastos(completionHandler: @escaping (Float) -> Void){
        let idUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName
        var total : Float = 0
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(idUser!).child("Gastos")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            if(value != nil){
                let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
                for i in value!{
                    myGroup.enter()
                    let j = i.value as? NSDictionary
                    let precio = j?["precio"] as? Float
                    let fecha = j?["Fecha"] as? String
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"
                    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: fecha!)
                    if(((date?.timeIntervalSinceNow)! * -1) < (30*24*3600)){
                        print("Total:" ,total)
                        total += precio!
                }
                     myGroup.leave()
                }
                myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                       print("Calculing in the function", total)
                   completionHandler(total)
               }
                }}
    }
```

Call the function and use `total` like this:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    nomUser.text = id?.displayName!
    correoLabel.text = id?.email!
    print("Calculing in View Controller", calculo.calculaBenef())
    calculo.calculaGastos { (total) in
      print("calculaGastos total: \(total)")
         gastosField.text = String(total)
         benefField.text = String(calculo.calculaBenef())
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

To my understanding:

`observeSingleEvent` is asynchronous, so it may or may not complete by the time `return` is called. Additionally, the `for i in value` starts only after `observeSingleEvent` is complete, so `return` is even more likely to be called before the tasks are completed. That's where `DispatchGroup()` and the completion handler come in.

When `myGroup.enter()` is called, it notifies DispatchGroup that a task has started. When `myGroup.leave()` is called, DispatchGroup is notified that the task has been completed. Once there have been as many `.leave()`s as `.enter()`s, the group is finished. Then `myGroup` notifies the main queue that the the group is finished, and then the `completionHandler` is called which returns total.

The completionHandler is also beneficial because of the way in which you're using `calculaGastos`. You're calling the function, and then you're using the return value to be displayed in a textField. Now that the completion handler is added, the `textField.text` is only being set after `calculaGastos` is complete and has returned `total`:

```
calculo.calculaGastos { (total) in
      print("calculaGastos total: \(total)")
         gastosField.text = String(total)
         benefField.text = String(calculo.calculaBenef())
    }
```

Hope that makes some sense! Glad the code worked for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you explain me a bit what do a completion handler and a dispatch group, why do you use that? Thanks!

Comment: Glad it was helpful! I just edited my response to explain a little bit of that.